# sending function/procedure and multi-dimensional array to subprogram in smalltalk

Tags: multidimensional-array, smalltalk

In Smalltalk are there functions or procedures?  Is it possible to send a function or procedure to a subprogram?

And in another question:  Can I send multi-dimensional arrays to a subprogram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I didn't understand your question. In Smalltalk there is nothing like functions, procedures or subprograms. It is all about objects and messages. A Messages implementation is called a Method.

Methods are reified as instances of CompiledMethod class. Hence, since they are objects, they can be passes arround by parameter, be stored in variables, etc.

Multi-dimensional array?? You have the class Matrix.  Is that what you want?

I would recommend you to read the first chapters of Pharo By Example book. It will help you to get an introduction.

http://pharobyexample.org/

Answer (score 1):

In Smalltalk, blocks are similar to anonymous functions. You can pass blocks as an argument in a message, just like you pass any other object as an argument.

But you should definitely read the book suggested by Mariano to learn the basic language concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please read the book, because your questions showing almost total absence of smalltalk knowledge.
In smalltalk there is only few concepts: objects and messages. A methods are implementing behavior for specific messages.

A special object - closure is one that you want. You can pass a closure as argument in some message (or store it in some object) and evaluate it at any point.